Using FrameworkElement to store usercontrol datacontext
i've managed to solve a problem that i faced trying to access viewmodel's properties from inside DataGrid control. The other problem is that i don't really understand why this works.
So basically the solution is to store the UserControl's DataContext inside a FrameWorkElement like so
<UserControl x:Class="EA.Dashboard.Console.WPF.Views.ReelsRFLInfoView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EA.Dashboard.Console.WPF.Views"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="this">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

and then refering the this FrameWorkElement inside the DataGrid like so, (this is adjusted for my goals)
<DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource MPN}" Binding="{Binding ManufacturerPartNumber}" Width="*"
                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowMpn, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisisbilityCollapsed}}"/>

But this is not enought, you have to also define a ContentControl that holds the FrameWorkElement as Content like so
<ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>

So i've ended up with this view
<UserControl x:Class="EA.Dashboard.Console.WPF.Views.ReelsRFLInfoView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:EA.Dashboard.Console.WPF.Views"
         xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
         mc:Ignorable="d" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
         x:Name="this">


<UserControl.Resources>
    <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>

<StackPanel>
    <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"/>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ReelsRFL}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ColumnWidth="*" Style="{StaticResource CustomDataGridStyle}">
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomDataGridCellStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolToHighlight}">
                            <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="DataContext.ShowHighlight"/>
                            <Binding Path="RflHours"/>
                        </MultiBinding>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource REELCODE}" Binding="{Binding ReelCode}" Width="*"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowReelCode, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisisbilityCollapsed}}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource ITEMCODE}" Binding="{Binding ItemCode}" Width="*"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowPartNumber, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisisbilityCollapsed}}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource MPN}" Binding="{Binding ManufacturerPartNumber}" Width="*"
                                Visibility="{Binding DataContext.ShowMpn, Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisisbilityCollapsed}}"/>

            <DataGridTextColumn Header="{StaticResource HRS}" Binding="{Binding RflHours}" Width="Auto">
                <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource CustomDataGridCellStyle}">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource BoolToHighlight}">
                                    <Binding RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}" Path="DataContext.ShowHighlight"/>
                                    <Binding Path="RflHours"/>
                                </MultiBinding>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</StackPanel>

Im not understanding why i need the ContentControl to make everything working fine. The idea to store datacontext inside and element and than use it through out code it's clear. But im not getting the role of the ContentControl, since it's not being referenced.
If anyone can explain that would be great. Many thanks :)

What's the purpose of the proxy element in the first place? The DataContext is already stored in the DataContext property of the UserControl itself so why do you need to to store it in another property of another object...?

Because DataGrid works differently from others controls, since it does not share inherited datacontext to its childs, or not all as i've understood. So when i tried to access UserControl datacontext from the inside of the DataGrid, i couldn't get it to work, it wasn't resolving path correctly. @mm8

It is correct that the DataContext of the DataGrid is not inherited by the column objects as they are not in the visual tree. DataGridColumn is just a layout placeholder and is not going to be rendered. DataGridColumn isn't even a Visual type. Instead, the DataGrid renders DataGridRow and DataGridCell item containers. The DataContext of these containers is the designated property value of the current row item (or cell value if the source is a DataTable).
This means you must bind your cells to the items in your ReelsRFL source collection. I mean what is the point in binding your DataGrid to this collection while you fetch data from a different data source? And how is that data going to map to rows? It looks like you are binding to properties of the same source object (your "ProxyElement"). All rows will show the same data.
But maybe those are meant to be additional static columns, in addition to the auto-generated columns? If this is the case, then you should change the design to get rid of the ugly "ProxyElement".
I suggest merging the static column data from the view model and the dynamic column data into a single data source e.g. DataTable.
Regarding the ContentControl: unless you are adding the "ProxyElement" to the visual tree, the binding that targets DataContext won't resolve. And if you add that "ProxyElement" to the visual tree e.g. by hosting it in a ContentControl the binding becomes redundant as the "ProxyElement" will naturally inherit the DataContext of the ContentControl. This means you can directly bind to the ContentControl and drop the "ProxyElement".
Another key XAML engine behavior is that "ProxyElement" is a FrameworkElement which itself is a UIElement.
Defining a UIElement as a resource results in instantiating that single object. Any reference to this object will yield the same instance. The instance is shared. This is different from styles or templates where each reference creates a new instance of the style or template.
Now, adding "ProxyElement" to the visual tree using the ContentControl will load it (FrameworkElement.Loaded is invoked) and resolve the data binding and enable DataContext inheritance (dependency property inheritance) and because the "ProxyElement" defined/instantiated in the Resources dictionary is the exact same instance like the one hosted by the ContentControl (shared instance), you can reference the "ProxyElement" as a resource without having to reference it via the ContentControl.
I hope you see the redundancy of the ContentControl as you could have added the "ProxyElement" directly in place of the ContenControl.
Regarding your control design: it's always a bad design to give the UserControl or custom control in general, awareness of the DataContext. You UserControl should not use the DataContext as this is reserved for external binding declarations in the client context. The DataContext must be expected to change based on were the control is used.
Instead, define dependency properties to access external data. Then the client can provide this data e.g. via data binding.
For example, implement an ItemsSource dependency property of type IList and use it as follows:
Client code
<!-- 
     ReelsRFL should be merged source (e.g. DataTable) 
     that contains data for both the static and dynamic columns 
-->
<ReelsRFLInfoView ItemsSource="{Binding ReelsRFL}" 
                  ShowReelCode="{Binding ShowReelCode}" />

Control internals
<UserControl x:Name="Root">
  <TextBlock Visibility={Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ShowReelCode, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}" />
 
  <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=Root, Path=ItemsControl}" />
</UserControl>


Thank you for your answer, i'm upvoting it because is a really good explanation on how things work, but, and maybe i wasn't clear on my question, or maybe im not fully understanding your answer, it's not quite what i was looking for. To be clearer, What i am trying to access from the inside of the DataGrid, are not other columns or data to display, but are like "parameters" also defined at ViewModel level. So for example if my ShowReelCode is false, the column displaying reelCodes data, so the column binded to ReelCode property of the object of the ReelRFL list, will be hidden, and so on

And yeah, i see the rendundancy about the framework element and the contentcontrol, that's why i was confused on the use of the content control  since i though i could just somehow using the framework element. But i think i've understand that part, so you are saying that i could just define the content control inside the stackpanel, that way its datacontext will be inherited from the usercontrol. And then i can directly reference to it from the datagrid instead of the framework element right?
1 last thing, i don't get the comment about the control design, about being aware of the datacontext

But originally i asked this question specifically to avoid defining that ContentControl, i mean i would like that the xaml is rappresenting the view and only the view, so what i actually can see. You know what i mean? To make things as readable and comprehensible as possible

"it's not quite what i was looking for. To be clearer, what i am trying to access from the inside of the DataGrid, are not other columns or data to display, but are like "parameters" also defined at ViewModel level. So for example, if my ShowReelCode is false, the column displaying reelCodes data, so the column binded to ReelCode property of the object of the ReelRFL list" - I think I understood you quite well. I was addressing this in the section about control design. The custom control must not know its own DataContext.

That's how controls should be designed. That's why you can use the native WPF control in every context with any DataContext. Currently, you want your custom control to know the DataContext to enable it to access its data (e.g. view model data). But instead, you must implement dependency properties and let the client context bind to it in order to provide the data. See the example I have provided with my answer. For example, your control must expose a ShowReelCode dependency property. Then from outside the control (client context) you bind this property to the view model.

Like the custom ItemsSource property in my example. This way the view model data gets into the control anonymously. Now changing the view model does not require you to change the custom control too. It's 100% reusable now as it is not aware of its DataContext. It only cares about its dependency properties to get external data.

"so you are saying that i could just define the content control inside the stackpanel, that way its datacontext will be inherited from the usercontrol. And then i can directly reference to it from the datagrid instead of the framework element right?" - Correct. But then I started to talk about bad control design in terms of the custom control knowing its own DataContext. When you introduce dependency properties the control does no longer rely on a specific DataContext. Hence, you don't need the proxy at all.

"i don't get the comment about the control design, about being aware of the datacontext" - I hope that got a little bit clearer now. If you find yourself having t reference the DataContext, which always means that the custom control must know the exact type of the DataContext value (that's bad coupling), then introduce a dependency property and bind to that instead. Then let the external code set this property via data binding (to the DataContext e.g. a view model class).

Ok clear, ye it makes sense, so i should create a custom control with specific dependency properties in order to avoid accessing directly to datacontext, but instead binding to that properties. Ok i'll suggest this to my supervisor. But going back to the original question, as ugly as i could be. Is there a way to avoid defining either the content control or the framework element to make everything work? I mean, as i said in my question, if i try to reference directly to the framework element without defining also the content control, it doesn't work, and i'm not really understanding why

I mean, all started because it couldn't manage to hide/display specific columns of my datagrid. The first thing that i though, was adding a property to the model of the objects of the list, in that case i could easly access them since the property it's visibile in the cell's datacontext. But didn't look quite a good solution. If you have any other ideas  to make this work, im open to everything

By "custom control" I meant a class that extends UserControl or Control (or ContentControl). I would prefer the latter because it offers a higher degree of customizability in contrast to UserControl. Adding the data to the row models would be much cleaner as this is where the data is used. The view model is out of scope. You can force it in but that is not clean and is likely to introduce other issues in the long term.

If the view model you are talking about is the same view model that also manages the row data models then it should be quite convenient to initialize the models with that data. You can also keep the properties in the view model and when they change then you update all the row data models with the new value.

*"I mean, as i said in my question, if i try to reference directly to the framework element without defining also the content control, it doesn't work, and I'm not really understanding why" - Then maybe my answer was not good enough in explaining that. The FrameworkEWlement is defined as a resource inside a resource dictionary. That dictionary is not a child of the current visual tree or any visual tree in general. Hence the resources aren't either. It can't bind to anything that is a child of a visual tree as it is completely disconnected.

There exists no external DataContext, hence a binding can't target it. That's why the binding set on DataContext (that requires a DataContext as it's implicit without an explicit Source) doesn't work. It can't get inherited because it has no visual parent. Bindings can't traverse (e.g. RelativeSource or Elementname) as there is no visual tree to traverse.

However, the moment you load it into the visual tree via the ContentControl the FrameworkElement now has a visual parent (the ContentControl) and is in the same visual tree as the UserControl. In this moment the bindings can resolve. The very specific binding in your case is absolutely redundant as it only sets the DataContext to the current DataContext which is already implicitly happening via data context inheritance. To sum it up: elements inside a resource dictionary are not loaded and are not a child of any visual tree (--> disconnected). Therefore, there exists no external DataContext.
